# what is the size of a ddrescue mapfile, relative to the disk image that I'm trying to repair?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ddrescue

I've got a 1TB hard drive image that I've copied to my /home partition (2TB) using `dd`. I have 277GiB free on that partition. I also have a 2TB external hard drive That has slightly more than 1T free.

I know that I have enough room for the disk image on the external hard drive. I'm planning on writing the mapfile to /home, and I don't want to run out of space there. I understand that the size of the mapfile may vary, but I don't know if the typical map file is on the same order of magnitude as the drive that I'm recovering, or if it's dramatically smaller.

I do know about the `--sparse` flag, which could decrease the size of the data that I'm writing to the external hard drive, but I don't know how much that's going to save me, and I don't have much room to play with on that disk.

Anyone have any experience with this? Are there ways to make the mapfile smaller? Can it be compressed on the fly?

Comment: Wait. You have already created an image of the hard drive using `dd`, the image is a regular file; right? And now you're going to copy the regular file to elsewhere; right? Where in this scenario is room for `ddrescue`? The tool is for reading from a possibly faulty block device. Using `ddresuce` to read a regular file only makes sense if you suspect the underlying block device or the filesystem to be faulty. Is this the case? Usually we use `ddrescue` where you used `dd`. I think I can answer your actual question about the mapfile, but I suspect there may be a need to fix the workflow first.

Comment: Yeah, the file system is pooched. I suspect the disk that I'm rescuing from is compromised; I wanted to touch it as little as possible.... I'm going to run ddrescue on the disk image, and write the output to the external drive.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to rescue from where.

Comment: To be clear, I'm going to be running ddrescue on the disk image that I `dd`'d off the compromised hard drive, and write the output to an image file on the external hard drive. When that's done, I'll `dd` from the external hard drive to a clean one (or possibly mount it as a loopback and just copy tiles that I want).

Comment: You have already read the suspected disk. Unless `dd` reported errors, the created image is most likely fine. Now it's a regular file and copying it with `ddrescue` will be like copying it with `cp`. There will be no errors unless the underlying filesystem or the underlying block device is faulty. Errors (if any) at this stage will be because of this filesystem or because of this block device, not because of the original device.